# Applying shadow to transparent image in Android

Tags: android, imageview, shadow

Is there a way to apply shadowRadius to a transparent ImageView in Android? For a TextView the following works:

```
<TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/textShadowColor"
                    android:shadowRadius="15"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="0" />
```

How can I achieve same effect for an arrow icon placed next to the text in Android? In iOS the following works out of the box:

```
Image("arrow")
  .shadow(color: textShadowColor, radius: textShadowRadius, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
Text("my text")
  .shadow(color: textShadowColor, radius: textShadowRadius, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

Comment: You want the arrow itself to cast a shadow? Or the outline of the imageview? Is it a bitmap or a vector?

Comment: The arrow itself, same effect like with text. It's a png.

Comment: This is probably doable somehow in Android. Is this effect to be applied to an undetermined number of PNGs or is it a finite number known in advance? If known in advance, you can simply user Adobe Illustrator or Gimp to do the shadows and just store them in your APK.

Comment: > "This is probably doable somehow in Android."

I'm waiting for all Android experts to shed light on it.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue. It is used as a sort of attribute to the text.

```
android:outlineProvider="bounds"
```

I obtained this information from: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/android%3Aoutlineprovider%3D%22bounds%22

Comment: It doesn't make ImageView support "android:shadowRadius="15"" attribute. Apparently it's just not supported in Android.